# Pandas Dataframes - Combine two Dataframes but leave out entry with same column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a DataFrame out of two existing ones. I read the title of some articles in the web, first column is title and the ones after are timestamps

i want to concat both data frames but leave out the ones with the same title (column one)

I tried

df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

but because the other columns may not be the exact same all the time, I need to leave out every data pack that has the same first column. how would I do this?

btw sorry for not knowing all the right terms for my problem

Comment: to make it clear here's an example:
df1 = {
   "Titel": "A","B","C","D"
  "Time": 1,2,3,4
}
df2 = {
   "Titel":"E","F","A","G"
"Time":1,2,3,54,3,2}

i want to concat them without the Column A to be replaced, commuted or whatever, just leave the already existing things out

Comment: Please use proper code formatting and include the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the duplicate rows from `df2` and then concat it with `df1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.title.isin(df1.title)]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: i have problems importing this to my project . do I need to replace the .title with the string the title is called or how do I access this column?

Comment: Yes, `.title` is how you access your column (I assumed it is named title). If you have a column name with spaces in it you need to replace it with this: `["column name"]`

Answer (score 0):

This probably solves your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns=['blah1','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah']
df2.columns=['blah5','blah6','blah7','blah8','blah']

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(len(df2.columns)):
        if df.columns[i] == df2.columns[j]:
            df2 = df2.drop(df2.columns[j], axis = 1)
        else:
            continue

print(pd.concat([df, df2], axis =1))
```